# Java FX Application unexpectedly closing in LINUX

Tags: java, linux, javafx

I made an application using Java FX to run in both Linux and window. The application running
fine in window and also runs in Linux but in Linux the application is suddenly closed without any exception in log and thus, the application need to restart again.

I am suspecting it may be due to java heap memory because the window OS has 3GB RAM
and Linux have 2GB Ram.

Can anyone help me why is it happening and what may be the solution ?

Comment: You will probably have to provide more data to get helpful answers. However, such an abrupt exit for a Java app is unlikely to be caused by memory problems. I suspect some native code failing. Are you using any? Maybe the video component or the `WebView`?

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was? My application also quits after 1.5h, with no error to be found. I am also using Java FX and I have checked if it was a memory issue, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Do javafx support in fedora ? The same JavaFx Application which run in window is also run in Mac OS but in Fedora abrupt exit after sometime.

Is is due to javafx not support in Fedora?

Answer (score 0):

I am using jnativehook to capture Keystroke and Mouse click

The same code is work fine and stable in window32, window64 and even Mac OS but in Fedora the code is abrupt exit after running sometime without any exception log